# Trying to install pymc error: invalid command 'config_fc'

Tags: python, git, pycharm, pymc

I'm trying to install pymc on osx snow leopard, but I'm getting nowhere.

*I have installed gfortran.
I have pyCharm as IDE.
I have cloned the git repo.*

Running the command 'python setup.py config_fc --fcompiler gnu95 build'

It gives me this error: 'error: invalid command 'config_fc'

I have no idea why I'm new to python. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
python setup.py install
```

see: [PyMC Installation -GitHub-](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc#installation)